# typescript documentation generator

Tags: javascript, interface, jsduck

i am starting documenting my java-script + typescript website with jsDuck
I've documented my class very well , but my problem is interfaces - they don't compile from the ts file over to the java-script.

here is my output, as u can see the page doesn't know who is **IComboBoxScope**
of course it understandable due to the fact it doesn't generated to the java-script

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIVKe.jpg

is there a proper way to workaround this in [jsDuck](https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck)?

IF NOT, is there other products or solutions for documenting js with typescript out there?, maaybe [jsDoc](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc)? ,[typeDoc](https://github.com/sebastian-lenz/typedoc/issues)?

sorry for the poor sample/photo, i am working on a private network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just wanted to share my findings, 
i have found a great solution [typeDoc](https://github.com/sebastian-lenz/typedoc) is really good, it doesn't need the compiled javascripts, it is dedicated to the ts files,
new solution, active environment and the great thing is that i only need to run a 1 line script with the project library as a parameter.

```
typedoc --out path/to/documentation/ path/to/typescript/project/
```

output [example](http://typedoc.io/themes/default/classes/controller.html)

i have seen options to change themes, class hierarchy is working very well
installed by NPM and support es 3,es 5 
great!.

Answer (score 0):

From JSDuck side there is no simple workaround as JSDuck has no concept of interfaces. You might document your interfaces as abstract classes for JSDuck, but it's not really the same. You're better off using a tool that natively supports TypeScript.